# Cannot find module '@babel/core' nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, babeljs

I'm getting below error:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module '@babel/core'
```

and below  is my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
"@babel/cli": "^7.8.4",
"@babel/runtime": "^7.9.6",
"cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
"debug": "~2.6.9",
"express": "~4.16.1",
"express-session": "^1.17.1",
"hbs": "~4.0.4",
"http-errors": "~1.6.3",
"mongoose": "^5.9.13",
"mongoose-paginate": "^5.0.3",
"morgan": "~1.9.1",
"multer": "^1.4.2",
"nodemailer": "^6.4.6",
"npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
"rimraf": "^3.0.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.9.6",
"@babel/node": "^7.8.7",
"@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.9.6",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.6",
"@babel/register": "^7.9.0",
"babel-core": "^6.26.3",
"babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
"babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
"babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
"nodemon": "^2.0.3"
},
"babel": {
"presets": [
  "@babel/preset-env"
],
"plugins": [
  [
    "@babel/transform-runtime"
  ]
]
}
```

I'm using nodejs express. this code is working in my own pc but it's getting error in the server.

I would appreciate any help.

Thank you

Comment: Did you do `npm install` (or `yarn`, if you're using yarn)?

Comment: @mbojko yes I have done that